# How to connect a socket to a server socket on a local network?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am making a messaging application that would connect two or more users on a local network and start messaging.It doesnot require an internet connection.
Now I don't know Where to make the socket and where serverSocket?
Who would be the client and who would be the server?
At the time the code that I've written is like this
....

```
static ServerSocket server;
static Socket client;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try{
            server=new ServerSocket(65474);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Port not Free");
        }
        while(server.isClose()==false){
             client=server.accept();
        }
        BufferedReader rdr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
```

From here ahead I will get the input from the client.
Is this code correct?Would client connect to the server correctly?

Comment: What guidance/tutorial/book/anything are you using to understand what you're doing? Doens't that have any other information to move you forward?

Comment: I've studied about sockets and serversockets and thier functions from docs.oracle.com and java2s.com/tutorials. I've just started working with sockets therefore the code may be wrong. But I couldn't find any example that would explain how to connect them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are infinitely accepting clients BUT you will never get to read their data.

You should put it like that:

```
while(!server.isClosed() {
     client=server.accept();
     BufferedReader rdr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    }
```

You can remove the ==false and just negate the boolean youre getting.
It will be set to true if it returns false and false if it returns true.

Dont forget to read the data and to display it on the screen like:

```
String receivedText = rdr.readLine();
System.out.println(receivedText);
```

Comment: How would i know when the client gets connected to the server using accept() function?

Comment: The accept function makes your program wait until a socket connects. It then accepts the connection and returns the connected socket.

Comment: Can u give an example code? I can't figure out at what point i have to connect a socket and at what point I've to get input from the user.

Comment: First off you have to establish the connection by accepting a request with ServerSocket.accept(). Then you read from the returned socket to get the data that was sent. And example is in the code i posted.

Comment: In your code above you are reading from the user in the while loop right after accept() returns a socket. Wouldn't that continue for infinity?
P.S as per my app two users or more have to send messages to each other so they all would need to connect to the same serversocket. How would you handle this so that server can accept connections from every client that tries to connect?

Comment: So youre trying to make a little chat program i guess. Well there is one way with different approaches. You could either use a List to store every Socket that connects or an Array of a fixed length. I would go with an Array in your case like: Socket[] clients = new Socket[8]; Also you would have to accept sockets asynchronously so the program can process messages and wait for a new client to connect. Which is where threads come into play. Try to find a nice tutorial since its kinda hard to explain everything as far as i know.